# SFINAE and implicit cast while function overloading

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, sfinae

I am trying to write a template helper that lets me check if a set of types matches the types of members of a struct. So far I have written this -

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional> 

struct foo {
    int field1;
    int field2;
};


template <typename...T, std::size_t ...indices >
constexpr bool construct (std::index_sequence<indices...>) {
    foo s = {std::get<indices>(std::tuple<T...>())...};
    return true;
}

template<typename...T>
static bool allowed(int) {
    construct<T...>(std::index_sequence_for<T...>());
    return true;
}
    
template<typename...T>
static bool allowed(long) {
    return false;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << allowed<int, int, int>(0); 
    return 0;
}
```

Here, obviously the call to `allowed<int, int, int>` is not valid because construct cannot be called (foo has 2 members and it is being initialized with 3). But there is another implementation of allowed which takes `long` as an argument. Since SFINAE, shouldn't the compiler simply match the second template implementation of allowed and return `false`? But it instead gives me an error -

> error: too many initializers for ‘foo’
>
> `foo s = {std::get<indices>(std::tuple<T...>())...};`

If I just comment out the first implementation of allowed, everything words fine and I get a false. I am confused w.r.t. how template substitution interacts with implicit casts and function overloading. If this is not allowed, is there a way I can achieve the same effect?

Comment: In your case your get an error in body when instantiating construct<{int,int,int},{0,1,3}>, type substitution is OK, so SFINAE doesn't kick in to filter out allowed<int,int,int>(int).

Comment: @Dmitry does SFINAE not apply to the body of the function? If the body of the defined function doesn't type check, doesn't it mean that this is simply a invalid substitution?

Comment: As far as I understand, substitution failures can only happen in the immediate context of the function type and its template parameter types.

Comment: @Dmitry I see, that makes sense. Thanks. I think I understand it now.

Comment: @Dmitry if you want to post an answer with the right way to do it, you can do that and I will accept it. Otherwise I will post the code I got working with your suggestions.

Comment: Nah, I'm in comments because I couldn't make it work with aggregate initializer. Go ahead and self-answer, I'm curious, too.

Comment: Ah, just got it working, lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`foo` is outside of immediate context thus you get hard error instead of SFINAE. 
Consider this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

struct foo {
    int field1;
    int field2;
};

template <typename U, typename...T, std::size_t ...indices >
constexpr auto construct (std::index_sequence<indices...>) -> decltype(new U {std::get<indices>(std::tuple<T...>())...}) {
    return nullptr;
}

template<typename...T, typename Q = decltype(construct<foo, T...>(std::index_sequence_for<T...>()))>
static bool allowed(int) {
    return true;
}

template<typename...T>
static bool allowed(long) {
    return false;
}


int main() {
    std::cout << "allowed<int,int>(0) = " << allowed<int,int>(0) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "allowed<int,int,int>(0) = " << allowed<int,int,int>(0) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Perfect! I did something similar with return type using `std::enable_if_t`, but this works too. Thanks